# Deserializing a list of objects from XML in C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I have the following Xml which i cannot change:

```
<myRoot>
    <User>
        <Name>James</Name>
    </User>
    <User>
        <Name>Jill</Name>
    </User>
</myRoot
```

I created a class to represent this xml:

```
[XmlRoot("myRoot")]
public class Users
{
  [XmlElement("User")]
  List<User> UserList {get;set;}
}

public class User 
{
   [XmlElement("Name")]
   string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

when i deserialize the xml I do get the right amount of records in the array. But the FirstName is always blank or null.

Please help.

Comment: Add `[XmlElement(Type=typeof(User ),ElementName="User")]`

Comment: Make serializable members as public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set both properties as `public`:

```
[XmlRoot("myRoot")]
public class Users {
  [XmlElement("User")]
  public List<User> UserList {get;set;}
}    
public class User {
  [XmlElement("Name")]
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

A cleaner option is to get rid of your `Users` class, which seems to be just a container for a list of users. You can just define the `User` class:

```
public class User {
   [XmlElement("Name")]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize a `List<User>` as follows:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<User>),
                                      new XmlRootAttribute("myRoot"));
using (var str = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"path\to\file")) {
  List<User> u = (List<User>)ser.Deserialize(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Add **[Serializable]** to your Users and User class.

Make FirstName and UserList be **public**

Comment: `Serializable` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Made my class public worked. Right after I posted this question I noticed that... but thanks anyway.